# Open .py file in Python IDLE edit mode on Windows 11

Tags: python, windows-11, file-association, default-settings

Recently I upgraded from Windows 10 to Windows 11. Then I reinstalled Python on my PC. Previously, when I right-clicked, it had the option in the context menu to edit the file with IDLE. When I clicked on that I could open the file with Python IDLE in Edit mode.
Now in Windows 11, I do not have that option. As a solution, I tried to set the default program to open .py file, Python IDLE from the below steps.
Right click on .py file.
Show more options
Select open with
Select choose another app
Pointing to Python IDLE installed on my PC there.

But when I did this, it was visible that app to open the file got changed to Python IDLE.
But when I click on the file nothing happens. It just opens a IDLE or command window within a few mili seconds and it gets closed just in a few mili seconds like nothing happens.
[image]

How to change this to open the file in EDIT mode on python IDLE?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try the below.

Right click the file
Open with
Then select idle.bat file.

You can locate idle.bat file in

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\idlelib
```

** Use your username in place of username.
Depending on the version of Python, the file location will change.

Or in my case, I have installed python right in C drive like below.

```
C:\Python311\Lib\idlelib
```

click on idle.bat. Click on the Open button.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate this answer, and I kind of muddled through finding the same for myself. What surprised me is that idle has an icon in a folder, and there's no way to associate the icon to python files and have it open idle... without somehow making the bat into an exe or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows 11. Then

```
1. Right click on .py file
2. Go to "Show more options" ( it is available at the bottom )
3. There you may see edit with IDLE option
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).